# Could this method of address assignment and use invoke undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

This was originally posted on *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174967/138048)*, where it was suggested Stack Overflow would be a better fit...

In looking for a method to search for, and capture a sub-string I coded this:

```
char string[] = {"this is the source string to search"};
char substring[] = {"string to"};
char *target;
char buf[80];


int main(void)
{
    target = strstr(string, substring);
    int len = strlen(target);
    strncpy(buf, target, len);
    buf[len]=0;
    return 0;
}
```

My question:
Could using the pointer char *target the way it is used here possibly invoke undefined behavior. If yes, how?

Comment: Yes it can, if `strstr` returns a null pointer.

Comment: ... which it will *never* do with this exact, precise code, as `substring` is clearly a sub-string of `string`. If you're asking if this is a great idea for a *general solution* the answer is absolutely *not*, for precisely the reason  mentioned above.

Comment: The `strncpy()` measures the length of the substring, assuming there was one (that is, that `strstr()` doesn't return null), and then deliberately fails to copy the null terminator into `buf`, and deliberately ignores the size of `buf`, though it does explicitly null-terminate the copied data after `strncpy()`.  With the code shown, this won't matter; the strings are short enough and `buf` is big enough (and `buf` is a zero-initialized global variable -- though it's valid to ask why `target` and `buf` are not local variables).  In general, such coding is sloppy and prone to buffer overflows.

Comment: Also, the comment you received on CR about using `memcpy()` is valid.  You could use `len + 1` to copy the null, saving the explicit assignment, but you should still limit yourself to copying no more data than will fit in `buf`.  You should also consider whether truncation is appropriate, or whether you should really reject the operation altogether if the substring is too long to fit in `buf`.

Comment: Although it isn't a risk in the code shown, nevertheless, I normally recommend using `memmove()` rather than `memcpy()` because it works regardless of whether the source and target areas overlap.  If you're not certain of no overlap, use `memmove()`.  (Note that the standard specifies: _Copying takes place **as if** the `n` characters from the object
pointed to by `s2` are first copied into a temporary array of `n` characters that does not
overlap the objects pointed to by `s1` and `s2`, and then the `n` characters from the
temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by `s1`._)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown in the question is 'OK' (with mildly clenched teeth) as written, but has multiple issues if it is intended to be an outline of a general-purpose 'copy from start of first occurrence of a substring to the end of string into another string' function.

- The global variables are undesirable.
- The lack of a separate function is undesirable.

In more detail:

- The code doesn't check that the substring is found in the source string; it should, because the code will dereference null pointers otherwise.
- The `strncpy()` measures the length of the substring, assuming there was one, and then deliberately fails to copy the null terminator into `buf`, and deliberately ignores the size of `buf`, though it does explicitly null-terminate the copied data after `strncpy()`. With the code shown, this won't matter; the strings are short enough and `buf` is big enough (and `buf` is a zero-initialized global variable -- though it's valid to ask why `target` and `buf` are not local variables).
- In general, such coding is sloppy and prone to buffer overflows.
- The comment you received on CR about using `memcpy()` is valid. You could use `len + 1` to copy the null byte too, saving the explicit assignment, but you should still limit yourself to copying no more data than will fit in `buf`.
- You should also consider whether truncation is appropriate if the string is too long to fit in `buf`, or whether you should really reject the operation altogether.
- Although it isn't a risk in the code shown, nevertheless, I normally recommend using `memmove()` rather than `memcpy()` because it works regardless of whether the source and target areas overlap. If you're not certain of no overlap, use `memmove()`.

Note that the C standard for `memmove()` specifies (emphasis added):

> ```
> void *memmove(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
> ```
>
> The `memmove` function copies `n` characters from the object pointed to by `s2` into the object pointed to by `s1`.
>   Copying takes place **as if** the `n` characters from the object pointed to by `s2` are first copied into a temporary array of `n` characters that does not overlap the objects pointed to by `s1` and `s2`, and then the `n` characters from the temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by `s1`.

No sane implementation of `memmove()` copies the data into an intermediate array as the standard suggests unless there is no reliable way of spotting the overlap between two arrays, which is seldom the case.  The implementers know the capabilities of the machine and can almost always avoid the double copy.

Here's a possible implementation of the code that truncates the copied string if it is too big to fit in the target buffer.  Other behaviours can be implemented to suit the whims of the application designer.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void copy_substr(const char *source, const char *substr, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    assert(source != 0 && substr != 0 && substr[0] != '\0' && buffer != 0 && buflen != 0);
    size_t length = 0;
    const char *target = strstr(source, substr);
    if (target != 0)
    {
        length = strlen(target);
        if (length >= buflen)
            length = buflen - 1;    // length = 0 would be an option too
        memmove(buffer, target, length);
    }
    buffer[length] = '\0';  // target might not be null terminated within length
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = {"this is the source string to search"};
    char substr[] = {"string to"};
    char buffer[80];
    copy_substr(string, substr, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("Main string: [%s]\n", string);
    printf("Substring:   [%s]\n", substr);
    printf("Tail string: [%s]\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Main string: [this is the source string to search]
Substring:   [string to]
Tail string: [string to search]
```

Comment: Have you observed what happens in `copy_substr(...)` if the output of `strstr(...)` is null?

Comment: Originally, it crashed. I've now fixed it so you get an empty string if there was no match. You need to fettle the various possible error handling behaviors to match your requirements. There isn't a single correct behaviour; there are many possible solutions that could be valid.

Answer (score 2):

This particular code, with the particular data that you are using, will not invoke undefined behaviour. However, some slight changes to the data *will* invoke undefined behaviour, so your code is very, very dangerous.

Undefined behaviour will happen if "substring" is not a sub string of "string", or if it is a sub string, and its first occurrence is 80 bytes or more before the end of "string".

BTW. strncpy (buf, target, len); buf [len] = 0; will do exactly the same as strcpy (buf, target), since len == strlen (target). In general, using strncpy is an accident waiting to happen.